# Cocos2d app crash, invalid spriteFrameName

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to develop an iphone game with cocos2d and I'm a beginner. 
I have some problems trying to show the number of lives in the upper boundary of the screen. So I want to start with 3 lives and decrease one of them at each error. This is my code

```
-(void)life {
    NSMutableArray *position = [NSMutableArray
                                arrayWithObjects:@"460", @"440", @"420", nil];
    spriteLifeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<life; i++) {
        spriteLife = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"cuore.png"];
        [spriteLife setTag:i];
        spriteLife.scale = 0.5;
        spriteLife.position = ccp([[position objectAtIndex:i] floatValue], 305);
        [self addChild:spriteLife];
        [spriteLifeArray addObject:spriteLife];
    }
}
```

and this is my function for the gameover and the the life removing

```
-(void)gameOver:(int)value punteggio:(id)punti{
    if (value == 1) {
        // partita vinta
    } else if(value == 2) {
        if (life > 1) { // 1
            life = life - 1;
            for (CCSprite *spr in spriteLifeArray) {
                if (life == spr.tag) {
                    [self removeChild:spr cleanup:YES];
                    [self actionBlink];
                }
            }
        } else { 
            //  partita persa
        }
    }
}
```

A file named "cuore.png" exists in the Resources Folder, But when I try to compile, after the splashscreen the app crashes. This is the log:

> 2013-02-11 19:55:06.635 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.1
>   2013-02-11 19:55:06.636 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: Using Director
>   Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink 2013-02-11 19:55:06.664 QuizGame[6672:c07]
>   cocos2d: OS version: 6.1 (0x06010000) 2013-02-11 19:55:06.664
>   QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
>   2013-02-11 19:55:06.665 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple
>   Software Renderer 2013-02-11 19:55:06.666 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d:
>   GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE 2013-02-11 19:55:06.667
>   QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096 2013-02-11
>   19:55:06.667 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH:
>   16 2013-02-11 19:55:06.667 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES:
>   4 2013-02-11 19:55:06.668 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL supports
>   PVRTC: YES 2013-02-11 19:55:06.668 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL
>   supports BGRA8888 textures: YES 2013-02-11 19:55:06.669
>   QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES 2013-02-11
>   19:55:06.670 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: GL supports
>   discard_framebuffer: YES 2013-02-11 19:55:06.670 QuizGame[6672:c07]
>   cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO 2013-02-11 19:55:06.671
>   QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas
>   : YES 2013-02-11 19:55:06.671 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: compiled
>   with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES 2013-02-11
>   19:55:06.672 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling
>   Support: NO 2013-02-11 19:55:06.695 QuizGame[6672:c07] cocos2d:
>   CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'cuore.png' not found 2013-02-11
>   19:55:06.695 QuizGame[6672:c07] *** Assertion failure in +[CCSprite
>   spriteWithSpriteFrameName:],
>   /Users/alexbava/Desktop/QuizGame/QuizGame/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:110
>   2013-02-11 19:55:06.696 QuizGame[6672:c07]**  Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid spriteFrameName: cuore.png'
>   ** First throw call stack: (0x2074012 0x1ca4e7e 0x2073e78 0x14e7665 0x6564e 0xc2bd7 0xc3229 0x40261 0xc1c4d 0xc12ec 0x9931af 0x9937a1
>   0x99494b 0x9a5cb5 0x9a6beb 0x998698 0x2d7cdf9 0x2d7cad0 0x1fe9bf5
>   0x1fe9962 0x201abb6 0x2019f44 0x2019e1b 0x99417a 0x995ffc 0xc0dcf
>   0x2665) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)

I think I've made a stupid error or something missing. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: accept either answer, keeps the list tidy for potential 'helpers'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the CCSprite constructor you took will look for a CCSpriteFrame object in the CCSpriteFrame cache. If you juste wanted to create a sprite from a file named 'cuore.png' use the constructor :

```
CCSprite * spriteLife = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"cuore.png"];
```

Sprite frames are typically used for animations, or managing large texture atlases that contain many (and sometimes unrelated) textures.

Answer (score 1):

spriteWithSpriteFrameName are generally used with CCSpriteFrameCache, please make use of 'spriteWithFile'. :)